# Automatic detection of indicator buffers and styles

Tags: mql4, trading, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, mql5

In MetaTrader 4 the styles (e.g. arrows or lines) that are used in an indicator are not chart objects. `ObjectsTotal()` returns 0. Of course I can read this out via `iCustom()`. But what, if the EA should react to all indicators with such symbols. So without knowing the number of buffers and/or the settings of the indicator. Is there a way to automatically search for such indicator styles in the chart and use them? Or to automatically recognize the styles used and the associated buffers in an indicator?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"Is there a way to automatically search for such indicator styles in the chart and use them?"*

No, there is not.

As of 2020-10, having spent 13+ years with MetaTrader4 trading automation projects, there is no support for such an automated feature re-discovery.

The code-units of Custom Indicator type hard-code the composition of Indicator Buffers (having external access-method via an `iCustom()` procedural interface) and GUI-style properties, not accessible at all by the user-level MQL4-{ Script | EA | Custom Indicator }-code.

If this were changed in the future releases of MetaTrader4/5 terminal, you would find details inside the documentation.

Comment: Many Thanks. I know an indicator which opens a GUI with a selection of indicators that are currently also in the chart (only those with arrows and dots, no indicators only with lines). If you select an indicator, you will be offered the styles (for example green arrow), including the buffer number. You can then specify that this should be a buy signal, for example. This indicator automatically recognizes arrows and points from other indicators, including the buffer number and color. So I think there has to be a way.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not exactly what u want but a oppurtunity

```
double  ObjectGet(
```

string   object_name,   // object name
int      index          // object property
);

Comment: Many thanks. But I think that doesn't help. It's not about normal chart objects, but about styles placed by indicators in the chart. And there I have no access with ObjectGet () .

Comment: bro if u attach the indicator to the chart, and the indicator displays object like a trendline u can get his name through journal and so now u can use this function to trade this object or whatever u want to do, there was a youtube video from jim dandy who showed hwo this works jim dandy is god of mql4 gl